# Mojolicious Lite Plugin "Log::Any" missing

Tags: perl, logging, cpan, mojolicious

When I load project with hypnotoad or morbo I get this error:

`Can't load application from file "/var/www/foo/bar.pl": Plugin "Log::Any" missing, maybe you need to install it?`

Here's a snippet from my applet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use LWP::UserAgent;
require HTTP::Request;
use JSON;
use Log::Log4perl;
use Validator::LIVR;
Validator::LIVR->default_auto_trim(1);

Log::Log4perl->init(app->home->child('log.conf')->to_string);
plugin 'Log::Any' => {logger => 'Log::Log4perl'};

my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger;

my $config = plugin Config => {file => 'config.pl'};

our $JSON = JSON->new->allow_nonref->utf8;

our $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
```

These are the packages I have installed:

- libapache-logformat-compiler-perl
- liblog-any-adapter-callback-perl
- liblog-any-adapter-dispatch-perl
- liblog-any-adapter-filehandle-perl
- liblog-any-adapter-log4perl-perl
- liblog-any-adapter-screen-perl
- liblog-any-adapter-tap-perl
- liblog-any-perl
- liblog-dispatch-config-perl
- liblog-dispatch-configurator-any-perl
- liblog-dispatch-perl
- liblog-log4perl-perl
- liblog-report-optional-perl
- liblog-report-perl
- libmoox-log-any-perl
- libmoox-role-logger-perl
- libplack-middleware-logany-perl

These are all the modules I have installed with CPAN (`cpan -l | grep -i log::`)

- Log::Dispatch   2.69
- Log::Report 1.29
- Log::Any    1.708
- Log::Log4perl   1.49
- Log::Any::Proxy 1.708
- Log::Any::Plugin    0.011
- Log::Any::Adapter   1.708
- Log::Any::Test  1.708
- Log::Any::Manager   1.708
- Log::Any::Plugin::Stringify 0.011
- Log::Any::Plugin::Levels    0.011
- Log::Any::Plugin::Format    0.02
- Log::Any::Plugin::Encode    0.011
- Log::Any::Plugin::Util  0.011
- Log::Any::Plugin::History   0.02
- Log::Any::Adapter::Stderr   1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Syslog   1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Screen   0.140
- Log::Any::Adapter::File 1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Base 1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::MojoLog  0.04
- Log::Any::Adapter::Stdout   1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Capture  1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Multiplex    undef
- Log::Any::Adapter::Log4perl 0.09
- Log::Any::Adapter::Test 1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Callback 0.100
- Log::Any::Adapter::Util 1.708
- Log::Any::Adapter::Null 1.708
- Log::Any::Proxy::Test   1.708
- Log::Any::Proxy::Null   1.708
- Log::Log4perl::Appender undef
- Log::Log4perl::NDC  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Resurrector  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Filter   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Logger   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Config   undef
- Log::Log4perl::DateFormat   undef
- Log::Log4perl::InternalDebug    undef
- Log::Log4perl::MDC  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Level    undef
- Log::Log4perl::FAQ  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Layout   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Util undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Catalyst 1.49
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::String undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::File   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::TestFileCreeper    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::Buffer undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::ScreenColoredLevels    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::TestArrayBuffer    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::TestBuffer undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::Synchronized   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::DBI    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::Socket undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::Limit  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Appender::RRDs   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout undef
- Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Layout::NoopLayout   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::Multiline undef
- Log::Log4perl::Util::Semaphore  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Util::TimeTracker    undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::JDBCAppender    undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::RollingFileAppender undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::ConsoleAppender undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::TestBuffer  undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::NTEventLogAppender  undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::SyslogAppender  undef
- Log::Log4perl::JavaMap::FileAppender    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Filter::Boolean  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Filter::StringMatch  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Filter::MDC  undef
- Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelRange   undef
- Log::Log4perl::Config::DOMConfigurator  0.03
- Log::Log4perl::Config::Watch    undef
- Log::Log4perl::Config::BaseConfigurator undef
- Log::Log4perl::Config::PropertyConfigurator undef

I just don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the [`Mojolicious::Plugin::Log::Any`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::Log::Any) module (by doing `cpanm Mojolicious::Plugin::Log::Any` for instance).

For what it's worth, I found that by googling "Mojolicious Log::Any", and one of the first results was the metacpan page of the module. (the point of this sentence is not to say that this is a bad question; just to suggest a google query for the next time you have a similar issue)